# UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character... problems

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, unicode

Before anyone gives me crap about this being asked a billion times, please note that I've tried several of the answers in many a thread but none of them seemed to work properly for my problem.

```
import json
def parse(fn):
    results = []
    with open(fn) as f:
        json_obj = json.loads(open(fn).read())
        for r in json_obj["result"]:
            print(r["name"])

parse("wine.json")
```

I'm basically just opening a json file and iterating it for some values. Obviously, whenever I read a value with some unicode in it I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "json_test.py", line 9, in <module>
    parse("wine.json")
  File "json_test.py", line 7, in parse
    print(r["name"])
  File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp850.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u201c' in position
15: character maps to <undefined>
```

As people said in other threads I've tried to encode it and whatnot, but then I get a similar error, no matter how I encode and/or decode it. Please help.

Comment: The problem is that you're printing to a Windows console that doesn't have any way to print the character. Python is detecting this for you before you get gibberish on the screen.

Comment: But when I paste the character `“` which is \u201c into the console I can see it just fine?

Comment: Have a look at [`cp850`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cp850), the character is not there. When I try pasting it on my system it gets substituted with `"`.

Comment: I see. What would you recommend I do?

Comment: I've already left my recommendation in the form of an answer.

Answer (score 16):

Everything is fine up until the point where you try to print the string. To print a string it must first be converted from pure Unicode to the byte sequences supported by your output device. This requires an `encode` to the proper character set, which Python has identified as `cp850` - the Windows Console default.

Starting with Python 3.4 you can set the Windows console to use UTF-8 with the following command issued at the command prompt:

```
chcp 65001
```

This should fix your issue, as long as you've configured the window to use a font that contains the character.

Starting with [**Python 3.6**](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-528-change-windows-console-encoding-to-utf-8) this is no longer necessary - Windows has always had a full Unicode interface for the console, and Python is now using it in place of the primitive code page I/O. Unicode to the console *just works*.

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing as a possible temporary fix (depending on if anyone have a better answer) was using [Unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode). Unfortunately I lost all the accents but maybe someone has a fix for that.