# Saving a dictionary as a file with columns which i can continously add to

Tags: python, file, dictionary, currency

I have a dictionary of currencies [here](http://openexchangerates.org/api/currencies.json) in [`JSON`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).

I will give a sample for simplicity:

```
{
    "AED": "united Arab Emirates Dirham",
    "AFN": "Afghan Afghani",
    ...
    "ZWL": "Zimbabwean Dollar"
}
```

And I wish to add them to a file where i can continuously add different sets of currencies at different times. The file should have a column for the code name of **currency** (e.g. "AED") and another column for **name**.

I really don't know where to start. Help to point me in the right direction will be very much appreciated.

My code for the dictionary is as follows:

```
import json
import urllib.request
def _fetch_currencies():
    f = urllib.request.urlopen(
        'http://openexchangerates.org/api/currencies.json')
    charset = f.info().get_param('charset', 'utf8')
    data = f.read()
    decoded = json.loads(data.decode(charset))
    print(json.dumps(decoded, indent=4))
```

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this.

1. Use csv as suggested in the answer

2. write json data to file ref. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309269/write-json-data-to-file-in-python.

3. Write a configParser file using configPraser https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply save your data in [`csv`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) with one line per currency:

```
AED, united Arab Emirates Dirham
AFN, Afghan Afghani
ZWL, Zimbabwean Dollar
```

To do that, you might want to transform your dictionary into rows, but in this case, it's trivial, since it's just the pair `(key, value)`:

```
rows = decoded.items()
```

Note, however, that the items will be in a random order, if you want the entries sorted, you can sort them before writing to the file:

```
rows.sort()
```

In the end, using the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html#csv.writer):

```
import csv
with open('local_file.csv', 'w') as my_csv:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(my_csv, delimiter=',')
    csv_writer.writerows(sorted(decoded.items()))
```

Putting it all together:

```
import json
import urllib.request
import csv

def fetch_currencies():
    f = urllib.request.urlopen('http://openexchangerates.org/api/currencies.json')
    charset = f.info().get_param('charset', 'utf8')
    data = f.read()
    decoded = json.loads(data.decode(charset))
    return decoded

def save_currencies(currencies, filename):
    sorted_currencies = sorted(currencies.items())
    with open(filename, 'w') as my_csv:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(my_csv, delimiter=',')
        csv_writer.wrtiterows(sorted_currencies)

save_currencies(fetch_currencies(), 'currencies.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this will help a lot.

Comment: Yes, it's fairly easy, plain text, well supported by any programming language, and editable with a standard text editor without really learning a syntax (look at the wikipedia link and the module documentation).

Comment: Dont you need a csvwriter handle to write to a csv file ? something like `csv.writer(my_csv,delimiter=',')`

Comment: When using the word decoded i get an "code analysis error" saying it is undefined, is there any modules i need to import before using it?

Comment: Well, `decoded` is the name of the dictionary you got in your function.

Comment: Oh yeah my bad i was doing it in a different section thus why it was not working

Comment: I've put it all together for the sake of clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`csv.DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) to handle easily the save file process. As `DictWriter` handles with dictionaries and the result of `json.loads` is dict, `DictWriter` do the job simpler.

```
import csv
import json
import urllib.request

def _fetch_currencies():
    f = urllib.request.urlopen('http://openexchangerates.org/api/currencies.json')
    charset = f.info().get_param('charset', 'utf8')
    data = f.read()
    decoded = json.loads(data.decode(charset))
    with open('names.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = ['code', 'country']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        for code, country in decoded.items():
            writer.writerow({'code': code, 'country': country})
```

Comment: File "C:\Users\daniel\Documents\Python Coursework\_fetch_currencies().py", line 16, in _fetch_currencies
    writer.writerow({'code': code, 'country': country})
  File "C:\Users\daniel\Anaconda3\lib\csv.py", line 153, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "C:\Users\daniel\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u02bb' in position 13: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the answer. Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25127935/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-character-problems)