# Change python 3.7 default encoding from cp1252 to cp65001 aka UTF-8

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, atom-editor

I need to change Python's encoding from [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) to UTF-8. I am using Python 3.7.1, [Atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(text_editor)), and the Atom script package for terminal.

I have read about *[PEP 540 -- Add a new UTF-8 Mode](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0540/)* (a solution to this? I don’t know how to implement or if useful) I cannot find a sound resolution.

Currently it cannot handle '\u2705' or others. When checking the Python file directory I found
...Python\Python37\lib\encodings\cp1252.py

```
# When I run
import locale
import sys
print(sys.getdefaultencoding())
print(locale.getpreferredencoding())

# I get
utf-8
cp1252
[Finished in 0.385s]

# Error for print('\u2705')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\en4ijjp\Desktop\junk.py", line 7, in <module>
print('\u2705').decode('utf-8')
File "C:\Users\en4ijjp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2705' in
position 0: character maps to <undefined>
[Finished in 0.379s]
```

I expect my terminal to handle the characters and display them when using print().

Comment: It's an encoding error, not a decoding error. It probably happens when you try to `print()` something – so it's not bs4's fault, but your terminal can't print the character in question. To be sure, we need the traceback.

Comment: On my terminal it prints `IPC-Store  ✅ ` So I presume the error isn't on BeautifulSoup's side

Comment: We still need the traceback to help you. In the given code snippet, I see no reason for a UnicodeEncodeError to occur.

Comment: The error is ultimately caused by `print(scrape_dict)` on line 236 (not part of the code shown), as I suspected. I think this problem has nothing to do with beautifulsoup; a script that only does `print('\u2705')` is probably enough to reproduce the exception.

Comment: If you write a Python script with just this one line `print('\u2705')`, what happens?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25128392) might help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character... problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25127935/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-character-problems)

Comment: True, in that case the linked answer won't help you. I know neither Atom nor Windows, so I can't really help. I suggest you delete all the bs4 code – it has no relevance here, I see no decoding problem, only encoding to STDOUT fails. If you have a really short question (your Python version, your editor/IDE, the print statement), chances are much higher you will get help.

Comment: You mention PEP 540, can you be specific about what arguments or variables you're trying to use?

Comment: I edited Q. I want python to change encoding to handle all utf8 characters. Cant do it in cp1252

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is resolved when putting the following at the top of your Python script. I am able to print all characters without error.

```
import sys
import io

sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.detach(), encoding = 'utf-8')
sys.stderr = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stderr.detach(), encoding = 'utf-8')
```

Comment: You're a savior!!!! Thank you so much! This is the best solution BY FAR!!!!